# Populating Select Box with Hash Array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Anyway I've created a Hash Array :

```
@example= ['A' => '1', 'B' => '2']
```

or Array

```
@example=[1,2]
```

here you've got the key (being the english name) and the value (the
generic equivalent).

what I want to do is make a drop-down single-selection box use these
key/value properties to render it correctly,

```
  <%= f.collection_select @example %>
```

...this doesn't work but what i'd like is generate the form code...

```
#from HASH
<select >
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

or

```
#from array
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For:

```
@example = [["A", 1, {:class=>"bold"}], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]] # {:class=> "bold"} is optional, use only if you need html class for option tag.
```

Try:

```
<%= form_for @whatever do |f|%>
# some code here..
<%= f.select :example, options_for_select(@example) %>
# rest of the code..
<% end %>
```

Or you can use:

```
<%= form_for @whatever do |f|%>
# some code here..
<%= f.select :example, @example %> # I am guessing that maybe you can not pass hash here for option tag.
# rest of the code..
<% end %>
```

Without form_for:

```
<%= select_tag :example, @example %>
# or
<%= select_tag :example, options_for_select(@example)%>
```

Comment: I don't want to use a form, how can I use this without form_for @whatever

Comment: Great, tks for your help